# Order of destruction parent and child

Tags: c++, class, smart-pointers

Why does C++ destructs the `Parent` class before the `Child` class? Would it not be more logical for an object when its goes out of scope to first destruct the `shared_ptr`s and then destruct itself? In my workflow this causes a problem, because my `Parent` class is managing an interface that the `Child` classes use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Child;

class Parent
{
    public:
        Parent() :
            child(std::make_shared<Child>())
        { 
            std::cout << "Constructing parent" << std::endl;
        }
        ~Parent() { std::cout << "Destructing parent" << std::endl; }
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Child> child;
};

class Child
{
    public:
        Child()
        { 
            std::cout << "Constructing child" << std::endl;
        }
        ~Child() { std::cout << "Destructing child" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Parent parent;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on the comments, I feel that my problem needs more explanation. My child classes are all allocated on `std::shared_ptr`, which get released when the parent goes out of scope. My main program is a CUDA program, and the parent has access to the GPU device. If the parent gets deleted, I no longer have access to the GPU. The destructors of the children, however, need to deallocate their GPU memory, and I therefore, want to have this action taken before parent goes out scope. But that means I manually have to delete the smart pointers, which in my view, defeats their purpose a bit.

Comment: What if you needed to access `child` inside  `~Parent`?

Comment: Look it at that way: If your destructor does some actual destructor work, the members still need to exist. You can't delete what a pointer points at if the pointer does not exist anymore, for example, right? So, when your cout is called, the child member still needs to exist. (Note that your example is not even about the order in which the objects are destroyed - only about the order in which text is printed)

Comment: _"In my workflow this causes a problem, because my `Parent` class is managing an interface that the `Child` classes use."_ What does it mean? Why it causes a problem?

Comment: To solve your problem, move the managed interface to a private base class. Base class sub-objects are created before member variables of the derived class, and destroyed after them.

Comment: @DanielLangr. I have a CUDA based program, where the device is set up on the parent. The children need to delete allocated GPU memory, but if the Device is closed before the destructors are called, I run into problem.

Comment: @Rotem. I do. And that is why I want to first nicely close all the children, before I clean up the parent. I mean, you also shut down your computer before you leave the office, right?

Comment: @Chiel I don't actually :) I don't understand the problem, the parent's destructor is exactly where you can clean up the children.

Comment: @Rotem. So my problem is the following. All my children are allocated on smart pointers. In the destructor of parent is the release of the interface to my GPU. The example first calls the destructor of the parent, which closes the interface, but only then the destructor of the children (at delete of the smart pointer when parent goes out of scope), which no longer can deallocate memory, because the device is unavailable. If I have to call manual releases of the smart pointer, why would I use them anyhow then?

Comment: @Chiel Wouldn't be better to have your GPU interface independent of `Child` classes? This is a nice case for _singleton_ I guess, which can be some `static` object (e.g., initialized and destructed within `main` or automatically).

Comment: @Chiel I understand your problem now. Other than redesigning the class structure, I think the simplest solution is explicitly resleasing the children in parent's destructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [destruction order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) is defined as (emphasis mine):

> For both user-defined or implicitly-defined destructors, **after the body of the destructor is executed, the compiler calls the destructors for all non-static non-variant members of the class**, in reverse order of declaration, then it calls the destructors of all direct non-virtual base classes in reverse order of construction (which in turn call the destructors of their members and their base classes, etc), and then, if this object is of most-derived class, it calls the destructors of all virtual bases.

A good justification is that the destructor of `Parent` may need access to its members for the purpose of releasing resources, not every object is self-contained.

Comment: Concerning your last statement: I exactly want to nicely close the children, before the parent kills itself.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it not be more logical for an object when its goes out of scope to first destruct the shared_ptrs and then destruct itself?

Not really, the destructor of `Parent` may need to access some members to do some kind of cleanup, so they need to be accessible and alive inside the constructor body. If you need to destroy the `Child` first you can always do it manually:

```
~Parent() { 
  child.reset();
  // do the rest ...
}
```

Comment: I dont think so. Smart pointers are designed to be flexible, in your case you don't want the automatic destruction because you need the `Child` to be destroyed earlier, so using `reset()` is perfectly fine.